# Self-Signed Certs unable to access links

Tags: ssl, openssl

I have been trying to understand why I cannot access these links from my webbrowser
or even when using:

```
wget https://secure.cprod.homeps3.online.scee.com/CommercePoints/MarketPlace/E/ThreadsCP.xml
```

error

```
# wget https://secure.cprod.homeps3.online.scee.com/CommercePoints/MarketPlace/E/ThreadsCP.xml
--2012-01-28 01:23:34--  https://secure.cprod.homeps3.online.scee.com/CommercePoints/MarketPlace/E/ThreadsCP.xml
Resolving secure.cprod.homeps3.online.scee.com... 217.18.28.81
Connecting to
secure.cprod.homeps3.online.scee.com|217.18.28.81|:443... connected.
OpenSSL: error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert
handshake failure Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

These links are normally requested from a client named Playstation Home.
How can we access these links without being on the client?

I have been doing a lot of reading about SSL lately and unfortunately I have tried to install the certs from the browser even have the certs and trying many different things to get access to the links, nothing has worked so far.

I would like to access them to get the latest content from the stores when the client is offline so I can see what I can shop around for when I use the client.

Is it impossible to get access to this link above? Should I stop looking for answers?

Comment: The link seems to require a client certificate (ie something only the "real" client (PS3?) has) and you don't have one, so the connection fails to set up.

Comment: I have all the certs from the PS3 I just don't know how to get acces or even use the certs properly.

SLL is a very tricky subject.
How would I install these certs and and use them?

Comment: Basic (a bit dated) overview how to do it in your browser at http://gryphn.phys.uconn.edu/prod/docs/certSetup.html, how to do it in wget I couldn't say (but I'm sure Google will answer that easily)

Comment: I have tried installing the certs and I have no results.. Nothing seems to work.

Comment: There must be some way around this or some other way of getting access to this file.. Please if some one can get access to this file I am more than interested!!

Comment: It's hard to do without the client certificates. There aren't all that many options, either the browser isn't sending them due to config, the server has some non standard way of requesting them that the browser doesn't understand or the certificates aren't the correct ones.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7123/discussion-between-ooo-star-ooo-and-joachim-isaksson)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two certs: 1) the cert file containing the server certificate with chain; 2) the client cert. Then you can try using "curl" command:

```
$curl --cacert server_cert_with_chain.pem --cert client_cert.pem "https://secure.cprod.homeps3.online.scee.com/CommercePoints/MarketPlace/E/ThreadsCP.xml"
```

The server cert chain file can be exported from browser: Firefox -> Preferences -> Advanced -> Encryption -> View Certificate -> Servers; select the cert under "Sony"; click "Export..."; select Format of "X.509 Certificate with Chain (PKCS#7)".

This exported file is in DER format. Use this command to convert it to PEM format:

```
$openssl pkcs7 -inform DER -in exported_server_cert -print_certs -out server_cert_with_chain.pem
```

Comment: Hey and thank you for your response.. I was thinking that this thread would become dead and I would never be able to solve this problem.
I am going to try your method above.. I just need to get the correct client cert as there is like  certs bundled into 1 .cer file.. I am not that confident in SSL but this sounds like a good approach and hopefully something will come out of it. Would help me a great deal.

Comment: I have managed to convert the certs into pem from the server but I am having problems with the client certificates.. I think I managed to convert them into p7b then into pem. but when I try and run the command in curl as stated above I receive this error

curl: (58) unable to set private key file: Type PEM

Kinda stuck on what to do with that..

Comment: Could you try adding "-verbose" to the curl command and see the detailed information?

Comment: I don't think I am using the Client cert properly because it was 6 certs in one file.. I basically split them up into individual certs and then used windows certificate export wizard to export into .P7B format. I just ran with the -verbose and tested it against all 6 client certs that I exported and converted into PEM and it returned this
* Connected to secure.cprod.homeps3.online.scee.com (217.18.28.81) port 443
* unable to set private key file: '/home/codes/certs/6.pem' type PEM

* Closing connection #0
curl: (58) unable to set private key file: '/home/codes/certs/6.pem' type PEM

Comment: Not sure what the message really means...it seems to complain about a private key, while what is needed here is the client cert (which is essentially the client's public key).